# Json Ignore Property on JsonSubTypes

Tags: json, jackson

I have a Scala case class that represents my JSON as below:

```
class MyJSON(x: Int, typeA: TypeA, typeB: TypeB)

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes(Array(
  new Type(value = classOf[ClassA], name = "ClassA"),
  new Type(value = classOf[ClassB], name = "ClassB")))
trait TypeA {
...
...
}
```

In my ClassA, I have certain fields that are deserialized from the JSON. But I also want that if there are certain fields that are not part of my Class objects, I want them to be ignored. What I did was I used the @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true) annotation on the MyJSON class as below:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
class MyJSON(x: Int, typeA: TypeA, typeB: TypeB)
```

It failed when my input JSON had some unknown fields. But when I moved this annotation to one of my Class (say ClassA) in my case, it was ignored. The problem is that I do not want to add this ignore properties annotation to all my classes, but rather I add it just to the top and want that propagated to all the types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a much elegant solution to the problem. I used Jackson MixIn mechanism to actually add the additional annotations to my target types during runtime. Here is what I did:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ Array("field1", "field2") })
abstract class MixInAnnotations{}
```

In my JSONMarshaller class where I create the ObjectMapper, I do the following:

```
  val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
  mapper.registerModule(new MyApplicationModule)
```

The MyApplicationModule now looks like:

```
public class MyApplicationModule extends com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule {

  public MyApplicationModule() {
    super(MyApplicationModule.class.getSimpleName());

    // Add the corresponding MixIn Annotations to ignore the JSON properties
    setMixInAnnotation(MyTargetClass1.class, MixInAnnotations.class);
    setMixInAnnotation(MyTargetTrait.class, MixInAnnotations.class);

  }
}
```

I call the setter methods to add the MixInAnnotations to my target classes. The target classes here could also be a trait that has the JsonSubTypes Annotation. So effectively, I'm not polluting all my types with the @JsonIgnoreProperties annotation.